# What is the best way to break NGXS state into smaller maintainable pieces, but keep them accessible for each other?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, ngxs

**Brief history of the question:**

I'am developing web assistant for [party game Mafia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_(party_game)), so the goal is to store single game in NGXS. Here's [gitlab repo](https://gitlab.com/consigliere-app/consigliere-client)

Game contains:

1. List of players
2. List of passed days(from 0 to somewhat about 5(typically))

[Player model](https://gitlab.com/consigliere-app/consigliere-client/-/blob/master/src/app/shared/models/player.model.ts)

Each day has three phases: Night > Day > Vote

[Day model](https://gitlab.com/consigliere-app/consigliere-client/-/blob/master/src/app/shared/models/table/day.model.ts)

To maintain this complex day structure and record all players actions I need really big amount of actions, so when `GameState` started getting huge I tried to break it up into child states. And here I ran into circular dependency issue.

Actually I've managed to solve it somehow, by reading this: https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/632

I created `CurrentDayState` and `PlayersState` as a child states, but in this case it seems like a bad approach, because this way:

- I'am only able to access state directly, and selectors with complex logic still unreachable at this point.
- I'am storing only current day and current vote, and then pushing them into days array in `GameState`, and it will be hard to implement going back to previous days if game host will need to check some information

I feel like my approach is a bit clunky, and I was unable to come up with any better solution. I could store all actions in root `GameState`, but this way .ts file will take up about 800 lines and it seems like a bad idea to me.

---

**The question:**

Is there any way to make NGXS state modular, but let every part of it access selectors from another part without running into circular dependency issue?
(Reading already meant issue, NGXS sub-states are supposed to be independant from each other and should have no control over each other whatsoever)

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this would be to consider each store as a database table and each new state you write as a new record/row in the table. Normalizing your models, you could have a player store and a day store. If you need the entire history of days and player states for a given day, you can continually insert new states rather than updating current states. Players may need an attribute to indicate the timing of that given state (like a foreign key pointing to the associated day state).

Selectors can be written to take the current state or lookup a given state for a given time in the history of the game if this is a business requirement. The ngxs documentation on selectors mentions joining unrelated states with [Meta-Selectors](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select). You could consider using these selectors to join the relevant player and day state together for a given lookup need.

**Edit 1:**
Normalizing the data and storing snapshots solves the dual-issues you mentioned about having complete game history and maintaining more management states.

For the specific question of maintaining different states without circular dependency, you should avoid importing two files into each other. Two ways to manage this off the top of my head:

1. Consider where you need the states joined - selecting one as the foundation for the primary business object - and only import the files one way into that state.
2. If neither of the states are the foundation for the primary business object, introduce a third state that serves this role and import the other states into this.

Then, use the Meta-Selector provided by NGXS and join the relevant states there.

**eg.**

```
export class DaysState{
  @Selector([DaysState, PlayersState])
  static getGameState(days, players) {
    return [...days, ...players];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
Storing snapshots for history seems like a good idea, but I didn't really get how normalizring models can help me to solve circular dependency issue.